# Alias to rank not able to use in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, rank

```
create table tab1(sno int, name varchar(30), age int);

insert into tab1 values(1, 'abc1', 22);
insert into tab1 values(2, 'abc2', 23);
insert into tab1 values(3, 'xyz', 28);
insert into tab1 values(4, 'abc3', 26);
insert into tab1 values(5, 'abc4', 25);

select sno, name, age, rank() over (order by sno) as ranking from tab1 where
ranking = trunc((select count(*)/2 from tab1)) + 1; //This query is giving error
```

Error is ORA-00904: "RANKING": invalid identifier

Comment: @TimSchmelter Edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to filter the results of your select based on value that is calculated after all filtering is done. You need to change it to something like this:

```
select * from (
  select sno, name, age, rank() over (order by sno) as ranking from tab1 
) where ranking = trunc((select count(*)/2 from tab1)) + 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is thank you define an alias in the `select` and then you want to filter by it.  You need to use either a CTE or subquery:

```
with cte as (
      select sno, name, age, rank() over (order by sno) as ranking
      from tab1
     )
select cte.*
from cte
where cte.ranking = trunc((select count(*)/2 from tab1)) + 1;
```

You seem to want to calculate the median value.  I would definitely not recommend `rank()` for this purpose, because of the way that it treats ties.  A better alternative is `row_number()`, so this is pretty close to getting the median.  And, you don't need the subquery:

```
with cte as (
      select sno, name, age, row_number() over (order by sno) as ranking,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from tab1
     )
select cte.*
from cte
where 2*cte.ranking in (cnt, cnt + 1)
```

This works well enough for both even and odd numbers of rows.

You might also be interested in the `MEDIAN()`, `PERCENTILE_DISC()`, and `PERCENTILE_CONT()` functions.